# Return from function, once value in function is null

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

I want to exit the current method/function in case a value of an Optional is not present.

i tried a naive approach to put a return statement into the .orElseGet() but that didn't seem to work. The best alternative so far seems to be:

```java
private void foo(Set<ISomeObject> someIterable) {

    Optional<ISomeObject> myObjectOpt = someIterable
        .stream()
        .filter(...)
        .findFirst();

    if(!myObjectOpt.isPresent()){
        return;
    }

    ISomeObject myObject = myObjectOpt.get();
    // do something with myObject
}
```

This doesn't seem better readable than the good old Nullcheck, any alternatives?

Comment: maybe `myObject` is a field? if so: do you want to update it only if `someIterable` returns a value? If not... are you using it later in the same method and only want to use it, if it is present? the `if` might be ok for the first... (but the `else` is not necessary then)... `ifPresent` might be what you are looking for in the latter case...

Comment: @Michael thx, i was missing that comment in the pseudocode

Comment: Note that using optionals is not necessarily resulting in code “better readable than the good old Nullcheck”. The key point here, is that the check can not be easily forgotten and there’s no ambiguity between a matching element being `null` and no matching element. So using a statement like `if(!myObjectOpt.isPresent()) return` might be fine in some situations. When it comes to readability, there is no reason to declare the `myObject` long before its initialization. Just write `ISomeObject myObject = myObjectOpt.get();` after the presence has been checked…

Comment: @ Holger, that's a good remark about the purpose of Optionals and the declaration. i adjusted the question. I guess there is no syntactical better way then.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a `Consumer` to `ifPresent` and do whatever you want in the consumer instead:

```
private void foo(Set<ISomeObject> someIterable) {
    someIterable
        .stream()
        .filter(...)
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(x -> {
            // do something with x
        });
    // do nothing!
}
```

Comment: That works, but would result in nesting, which is harder to read :/

Comment: I would consider this the conventional solution. For most purposes I like it. There may of course be situations where it will not be the most readable. If you keep `myObjectOpt` form your question and then do `myObjectOpt.ifPresent(`…`);`, you may find it clearer? Or would it help putting what you want to do with `myObject`/`x` into a separate method? Then you only got `.ifPresent(this::yourNewMethod);`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems you want to set the value of `ISomeObject myObject` in case that Optional is present, one way to do it:

```
ISomeObject [] myObject = new ISomeObject[1]; // effectively final strikes again!

Optional<ISomeObject> myObjectOpt = someIterable
    .stream()
    .filter(...)
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(x -> myObject[0] = x);
```

But even simpler would be:

```
myObject = someIterable
        .stream()
        .filter(...)
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(null); // in your code myObject is null by default anyway
```

But even this makes very little sense, you are setting that field and then doing nothing with it? Why do that in the first place then?

Also, `findFirst` from a `Set` makes little sense, of course.

Comment: why should `findFirst` make little sense in a `Set`? if the `filter` is just very basic, e.g. `someObj -> someObj.getName().contains("x")`, there can be several matches...

Comment: @Roland does a `Set` has _any_ order? Run this `String first = Set.of("aa", "ba", "ca", "da")
                          .stream()
                          .filter(x -> x.contains("a"))
                          .findFirst()
                          .get();

        System.out.println(first);` a few times in java-9 or higher

Comment: A `Set` can have a meaningful order, e.g. it might be a `SortedSet` or a `LinkedHashSet`. Besides that, I don’t see any advantage in showing the dubious array based solution before the simpler and cleaner one.

Comment: @Eugene Both of your solutions would still necessitate a Nullcheck of myObject. Remember, my main problem is to exit the function if myObject == Null

Comment: @JulianDm why not `ifPresent(x -> do something with that x)`?

Comment: following this approach, if i need a filter on `someOtherIterable1` and `someOtherIterable2` it would result in some heavy nesting, right? -> Also not really satisfying.

Comment: @JulianDm oh well, not every solution is very "satisfying"